# Ftp Polling as service in Spring Integeration

Tags: spring-integration

In my application.I need to poll files from FTP Server.But the current load will be very less say per day we will get 2-3 files.so i don't want my service to run always and uses the resources.

Is there any in build or with little customization can i start/stop my FTP polling on demand.
Basically i want this FTP polling as service in UNIX. so that when required stop/start.

Am using Spring Integration's int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is an issue to keep Object in the Java Heap and don't affect GC...

If you have such a low polling interval you can use `cron` option on the `<poller>` to run the polling task once-twice a day.

From other side you can, of course, start/stop any Spring Integration Endpoint using its `id` and `Lifecycle` `start/stop` management operations.

In addition you can `expose` your endpoint to the [JMX](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#jmx-mbean-exporter) and start/stop them from there, or just rely on the [Control Bus](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus) in your app to do the same.